# Names of NAD+ and NADH

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, organic-reduction, organic-oxidation

As part of the biochemical process of glycolysis, NAD<sup>+</sup> is reduced to NADH. In other words, nicotinamide adenine dinucleotide is reduced to... nicotinamide adenine dinucleotide?

Everywhere I look tells me that NAD<sup>+</sup> and NADH refer to the same particle with the same name, just in an oxidized or reduced form. However, NADH has one more hydrogen atom then NAD<sup>+</sup>, so shouldn't these particles have different names?

Answer (score 2):

The H stands for [hydride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydride), but most everyone just shortens nicotinamide adenine dinucleotide hydride to NADH.